# How do I resolve the error ORA-06413: Connection not open?

Tags: vb.net, oracle

My local environment VS2012

Using Oracle 10g XE

```
Dim dbConn As New OleDbConnection

Dim dbComm As OleDbCommand

dbConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=msdaora;Data Source=XE;User ID=scott;Password=tiger"

dbConn.Open()
```

Tip error: ORA-06413: Connection not open.

Already check the TNSNAMES.ora, SQLNET.ora, LISTENER.ora and its nothing wrong.

But why this error appear?
:(

Comment: Can you make a connection using sqlplus.exe in the oracle bin directory. That should tell you if things are set up right.

Comment: Not sure what your directory structure is but I see write a lot of issues like this by googling this error returned by vb http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d578dfe3-5bc3-4bce-9b9e-85b2e9d2f5de/ora06413-connection-not-open

Answer (score 7):

The error is caused by the parenthesis in the pathname.

possibly you execute VS2012 from C:\program file (x86)...

workaround: create a junction link

steps:

1. from: command line execute

   ```
   C:>mkLink /j "Program Files x86" "Program Files (x86)"
   ```

   and then
2. fix the (or create a new) shortcut with new path (C:\program file
   x86...)

Comment: Works, but you needed to add "and then" between your #1 and #2.  I first got the impression it was an "OR" between your #1 and #2, like you could do one or the other.  I quickly found these can't be done independently, or exclusively.

Answer (score 2):

I worked a lot on this problem, I lost a lot of time. Apparently IIS Express in Visual Studio uses the Oracle provider 64 bit.

To solve this problem:

1. I installed IIS on my PC (Windows 10)
   with .NET 4.5 or higher
2. I compiled the Web API application with 32-bit target.
3. I publish the web application on my IIS.
4. On IIS I set enable the apps 32 bit to true

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolved the problem installing Oracle 11g Express. Before, I removed all previous Oracle client installation. I use windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Create Bat file to start excel 
in bat put path you can adjust to match your folders

start c:\progra~2\micros~1\Office14\Excel.exe

When you start excel just open macro and try :)

Comment: This is not about how to start excel in a batch script. Please check that your answers match the question.

Comment: Voted back to zero... If the Excel Spreadsheet has a Oracle connection then this is the fix.

Answer (score 0):

1. uninstall your toad or oracle
2. reinstall on on your window drive ex:(c/d/e) in new folder

don't install in program files (x86)

because program files(x86) is for 32 bit applications

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when working on my Visual studio 2013 project. I was able to run the same project from SVN on a different machine, but it just WON'T work on mine. I checked the connection string and could successfully test the connection in Oracle, but it would throw a disgusting “ORA-06413: Connection not open” error from code.

I got it fixed this way - Install Oracle 11g client -> Select "Administrator" as Type of Installation. Re-open Visual Studio and it worked. Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved the error after the days of searching.

**Error Cause:**

This error is due to Oracle reserved character "(",")" and in Windows 64 bit there is a folder "Program Files (x86)" which is a creation problem.

**Solution:**

Create a link folder for "Program Files (x86)" using below command on Window Drive path.

1. Open `cmd` as Administrator.

   ```
   mklink /j "Program Files x86" "Program Files (x86)"
   ```

   or visit link
   [download3k article](http://www.download3k.com/articles/MKLink-Explained-Create-Symbolic-Links-that-Simplify-File-Management-in-Windows-Vista-7-and-8-00437)
2. Open Registry (as Administrator)->Export Registry

   Always backup a registry file before changing it. Make a copy of the registry file and work on the copy.

   Open Registry file(Copy) in text editor and replace "(x86)" with "x86"

   Save the file and import it to your Registry and restart your computer.

Now the "ORA-06413: Connection not open" error goes away.

Comment: Should've said specifically where in the registry to change (x86) to 86, but even better is to simply create a shortcut to Visual Studio using the new path, like was suggested in another answer, than to go editing the registry where there are many, MANY places that could need to be changed that have (x86) in their path.