# Error connecting to Oracle DBA: connection not open

Tags: excel, vba, oracle

I have written code in VBA to connect to Oracle DBA. But after running the code the error pops up

> ORA-06413: Connection not open.

My System

- Windows 8 64 bit
- Microsoft office professional plus 2013 32 bit.
- oracle is 32 bit.
- ODBC DSN is set as myORA 32 bit.

The code is running well in windows 7. I want to fix this ot also work on Windows 8 because of an upgrade in the system.

Comment: Can you put some detail to "oracle is 32 bit". Is it the driver?

Comment: Oracle is database.... and the version is 11g(32 bit).

Comment: You must also make sure that your Oracle Client runs 32 bit, since you have Office 32 bit.

Comment: Presumably you're getting that error when you try to use the connection i.e. issue a query over it? Is your code checking for (or suppressing) any error thrown at the point you connect?

Comment: The code throws an error at Conn.open in VBA

Comment: Would help a lot to show your actual code.  Maybe also check here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003631/how-do-i-resolve-the-error-ora-06413-connection-not-open

Comment: Please show us your code where the error happens.

Answer (score 1):

**ADO example**

Maybe you have to update your connection string.
Please refer to https://www.connectionstrings.com for examples.

Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects (ADO)
needs a reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library"

```
Sub ConnectToOracleViaADO()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim myResult As String

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    cn.ConnectionString = "{Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=myServerAddress; _
        Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;"
    cn.ConnectionTimeout = 5
    cn.Open

    If cn.State <> adStateOpen Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, couldn't open database connection.", _
            vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    cn.CommandTimeout = 1

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open Source:="SELECT something;", _
        ActiveConnection:=cn, _
        CursorType:=adOpenStatic, _
        LockType:=adLockReadOnly, _
        Options:=adCmdUnspecified
    myResult = rs.Fields(0).Value

    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```